# How to handle null and NULL value in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

So I have been facing this weird situation in mysql where somehow null values are inserted in my table.
I'm talking about **null** value not **NULL** value.

I have attached image for better understating

[image]

as you can see name column have null and mobile_no have **NULL**

So after using this query

```
select Case when t1.name IS NULL then 'NA' 
            when t1.name= 'NA' or 'null' or NULL then 'NA' 
            else t1.name end as 'Name', 
       Case when t1.mobile_no IS NULL then 'NA' 
            when t1.mobile_no= 'NA' or 'null' or NULL then 'NA' 
            else t1.mobile_noend as 'Mobile no' from student;
```

after this I'm getting this result

```
|Name|Mobile no|
----------------
|null|NA       |
```

but I want below result

```
|Name|Mobile no|
----------------
|NA  |NA       |
```

Comment: You can't test against multiple values like this: `when t1.name= 'NA' or 'null' or NULL then 'NA'`. Use `WHEN ti.name IN ('NA', 'null') THEN 'NA'`.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, your solution worked. Please post your ans as solution I'll mark it as Answer.

Comment: SQL is case-insensitive. There's no difference between `NULL` and `null` values. I think you mean a `'null'` string.

Comment: @Barmar yes it was actually null string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare a column with multiple values use `col IN (x, y, z)`, not `col = x OR y OR z`.

You also can't compare with `NULL` using `=` or `IN`, so that has to be a separate check.

```
select 
    Case 
        when t1.name IS NULL OR t1.name IN ('NA' or 'null') then 'NA' 
        else t1.name 
    end as 'Name'
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try use IN statement? That should work.

```
select Case WHEN (t1.name IN ('NA', 'null') OR t1.name IS NULL) THEN 'NA' else t1.name end as 'Name', 
Case WHEN (t1.mobile IN ('NA', 'null') OR t1.mobile IS NULL) THEN 'NA' else t1.mobile_no end as 'Mobile no' from student;
```

Comment: Yes it worked @Barmar also gave the same solution. It was just silly syntax issue.

Comment: You can't put `IS NULL` inside `IN (...)`

Comment: Ok then, wish you good work.